# Disable Visual Studio 2022 Sign In prompt?

Tags: visual-studio

I recently upgraded to VS 2022 17.2.0. Now, every time I start up VS, I get prompted to sign-in. The dialog says "Visual Studio" across the top, and has a button labeled "Sign-in options" on the bottom.

I have no interest in linking to a Microsoft account.

I've gone into Tools | Options | Environments | Accounts and unchecked all the checkboxes. Still getting the sign-in prompt.

Any way to disable it? This only started happening on 17.2.0.

NOTE: this is NOT the dialog with the "Not Now" option.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I've been experiencing exactly the same problem, and I'm slightly dissapointed no one else has been able to find a solution...

Here's what I eventually figured out:
In your visual studio install, go to the following folder:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\ServiceHub\Hosts\ServiceHub.Host.CLR.x86

There's an executable named "ServiceHub.IdentityHost.exe". I simply closed Visual Studio, then renamed that exe to "ServiceHub.IdentityHost_disabled.exe" so it doesn't run when VS starts.

As of my most recent test, that appears to remove the login prompt entirely.

A note of warning: Do not open "Account Settings..." from within Visual Studio. The window will appear mostly empty, and if you close that Visual Studio will crash because it's waiting on the service that we've disabled.

Comment: I applied the fix in the Pro version and Account Settings was blank like you said, but it didn't crash on the close. But the sign in dialog is gone! Nice fix!

Comment: Like SledgeHammer, I tried to open/close the Accounts window after applying the fix, and closing the Accounts window did not crash VStudio. THANK YOU for the fix! It amazes me that MS would put up a forced login window on every boot of VS on every project around the world (sigh).

Comment: This didn't work for me, unfortunately. If anyone else has come up with another solution, I'd be happy to give it a try.

Comment: Mine was under ...DOTNET.x64 but same concept.

Answer (score 6):

<strike>You might want to check VS 2022 17.2.6, there is a fix for a "meaningless OS sign-in dialog during launch".</strike>

Either the fix was reverted, or the release note was for another issue. Either way, the sign-in dialog is again/still here now (17.3.x).

Comment: lol, yeah "meaningless" I bet. More like they got a lot of backlash and reverted it ;).

Comment: Currently on 17.3.6 and the cat came back.

Comment: I don't know that it ever went away, that's why I said that it needed to be checked. I don't know what triggers it (updates? time? ...) so I couldn't verify myself. But when I saw that mention of the sign-in dialog in the release notes of 17.2.6, I was hopeful.

Answer (score 1):

For users of VS 2022 Professional editions, the executable

Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.exe, located in

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\ServiceHub\Services\Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService

is the file that must be renamed.