# Visual Studio 2022 login window on startup

Tags: visual-studio

Does anybody experience and know to fix this window every time Visual Studio 2022 is started?

[image]

It always pops up when I open Visual Studio 2022 and even if I pick the account that I use, It will load for a few minutes, then, it will not proceed and keeps coming back to the account selection window.

[image]

I already tried logging out and in but it has no effect.

[image]

Comment: It's a bit of a hack but, does this answer your question? [Disable Visual Studio 2022 Sign In prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72249977/disable-visual-studio-2022-sign-in-prompt)

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72249977/17003367) might help.

However, I've not found a better solution yet.

Comment: This should really be a comment - link only answers are discouraged as the answer becomes unusable if the link gets broken. You should include enough relevant information from the linked resource to actually answer the question. By all means, keep the link in the question but only for more information.

Comment: Given that your link is to another question then it may be more appropriate to leave it as a comment (50 rep) or raise a close vote (3,000 rep) unfortunately though as a new user you are not able to do either of these!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).